# spring-data-cassandra CassandraRepository creates SimpleStatement or PreparedStatement in newer version

Tags: sql, cassandra, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, datastax

We were using spring-data-cassandra version 2.1.10.RELEASE. Now upgraded to 3.0.1.RELEASE. The change we are seeing is that it does not use `PreparedStatement` anymore when I use `CassandraRepository` interface.  My repository class looks like:

```
public interface TableClassRepository extends CassandraRepository<TableClass, PrimaryKey>
```

Earlier the findById query was like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name_1=? and column_name_1=?
```

But now:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name_1=111111 column_name_2=22222
```

As I understand prepared statement is well optimized from Cassandra point of view. Could someone please help me understand if spring data changed its implementation or I am doing something wrong?